# 7zip - Add item in a right click menu for timestamped archive

Tags: zip, 7-zip, archiving

Is it possible to add an item in 7zip right click menu. Every once in a while, I would like to make a backup of the file/folder and would like to add today's time stamp. For example,

**sample_project** folder would be **2020-06-18_sample_project.7z** (or similar)

[image: timestamp in 7zip file]

I understand that I can use some kind of versioning system and I do use Git. But these files/folders are not suitable for that. All, I am looking is a quick way to archive the file/folder (with timestamp), before I start editing that file.

Thank you.

(Note: it doesn't have to be 7z)

Answer (score 0):

- First open registry editor as Administrator.
- Then navigate to the key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\7-Zip`.
- Then create a sub key named `Compress and date time stamp`.
- Click the sub key you just created and add another subkey named `command`.
- Now edit the default value of `command` key to `powershell.exe -noprofile -command "& { $stamp = (Get-Date).ToString("yyyy-mm-dd");   7z.exe a -t7z "$($stamp)_%1.7z" %1}"`.

Comment: Thanks I get this error though. `Missing ')' in method call, (Get-Date).ToString(yyyy-mm-dd)' `.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

- Open `regedit.msc`
- Navigate to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell`
- Create a sub key named `7-Zip With Date` (This arbitrary name will be displayed in the context menu)
- Click the created sub key and add another subkey named `command` (This name is mandatory)
- Edit the default value of the `command` key and input the command to execute

  - `powershell.exe -noprofile -command "& { $stamp = (Get-Date).ToString(\"yyyy-MM-dd\"); & \"c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe\" a \"%1-$($stamp).zip\" \"%1\"; }"`
- Output is `example-2021-11-14.zip`

Comment: Thank you. However, there are two issues. It is only applicable to Folders. And even when I tried to create timestamped zip file for a folder, it did create a zip file, but there was nothing inside the zip file. Update: I just learnt that if the folder has spaces, it does not work.